# Netbeans not recompiling

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

New to Java and Netbeans.  Recently Netbeans appears to have stopped compiling when hitting F6.  The changes just aren't reflected in the Netbeans output tab.  I have to 'Clean and Build Project' (Shift-F11) and then F6 for the changes to appear in the output.  Does this have anything to do with [Compile on Save](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave)?  I have compile on save enabled in the project properties.  What's going on?

I am using a newly created project (from `File -> New Project`).  I recently updated from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04.  Info from the Netbeans `Help -> About` box:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.9 (Build 100825-unknown-revn)
Java: 1.6.0_22; OpenJDK Client VM 20.0-b11
System: Linux version 2.6.38-8-generic running on i386; UTF-8; en_GB (nb)
Userdir: /home/anthony/.netbeans/6.9
```

Comment: Ok so that functionality has returned.  No idea why.  Very weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When "Compile on save" is enabled, then there is no compilation step when you run your application (actually that's the advantage of having "Compile on save" enabled)

Consequently the compile menu item (F9) is also disabled in that case - because compilation of a single class is not necessary as it is done during save.